# Search keyword using linq in asp.net with c#back end

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
    List<search> alllist = wsWSemloyee.GetAllProject(); //where search is model class contains properties..
    string search_key = "%" + txtsearch.Text.Trim() + "%";


    List<search> result = new List<search>();
    foreach (search item in alllist)
    {
     var op = (
                     from a in alllist
                     where a.Sfirstname.Contains(search_key) || a.Slastname.Contains(search_key) || a.Smob.Contains(search_key) || a.Scity.Contains(search_key) || a.Sstate.Contains(search_key)
                     //where SqlMethods.Like(a.Sfirstname,search_key)||SqlMethods.Like(a.Slastname,search_key)||SqlMethods.Like(a.Scity,search_key)||SqlMethods.Like(a.Smob,search_key)||SqlMethods.Like(a.Sstate,search_key)
                     select a
                   );

   //  List<search> lst = op.ToList<search>();
        if (op != null)
        {
            result.Add(item);
        }
    }


    if (result.Count != 0)
    {
        dgv_searchreport.DataSource = result;
        dgv_searchreport.DataBind();// data grid view
    }
```

its not working...
giving all result present in alllist..
//where search is model class contains properties..

Answer (score 1):

I'ts because you are comparing if result of your linq query is not null and then adding variable from foreach clause. When any single item from allproducts will match condition then op will be never null and then whole collection will be contained in result. What you want is probably following:

```
var result = (from a in alllist
              where a.Sfirstname.Contains(search_key) 
                    || a.Slastname.Contains(search_key) 
                    || a.Smob.Contains(search_key) 
                    || a.Scity.Contains(search_key) 
                    || a.Sstate.Contains(search_key)
              select a).ToList();
```

That will pick all items which match condition and enumerate them to list.

Answer (score 0):

May this helps you..

```
      string search_key = txtsearch.Text.Trim(); // instead "%" + txtsearch.Text.Trim() + "%";

        List<search> result = new List<search>();            
        var op = (from a in alllist
                     where a.Sfirstname.Contains(search_key) || a.Slastname.Contains(search_key) || ......
                     select a);

        if(op.Count() > 0)
        result = op.ToList();
```

Comment: if you're calling .Count() and then op.ToList() then you're enumerating twice.  It's better just enumerate to list and then check if it's empty. Usage of .Any() is also better way since it's enumerating just to first item.